# JAVA/Oracle-weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.poolconnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_t4cconnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleconnection

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ebs

existing code 11i , we are migrating to R12.2.6

for one of the JSPs , am getting the below error from ($EBS_DOMAIN_HOME/servers ) oracore_server1.log

> weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.poolconnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_t4cconnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleconnection

inside the jsp file there is a code like

code is below

> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection connection = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection)
>
> oracle.apps.jtf.aom.transactions.TransactionScope.getConnection()

please tell me if this is the part of the issue ? if yes how could we rewrite it for R12.2.6

Let me know if you need any more information .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some driver issue - in EBS R12 we need to do drop the

> .driver

and the below code works.

> oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection connection = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)